# Умножение с использованием побитового

Tags: c++

Имеется функция, которая производит умножение двух чисел.

```
int mult(int a, int b) {
  int result = 0;
  while (b != 0) {
    if (b & 0x1 == 0x1)
      result += a;

    b >>= 1;
    a <<= 1;
  }
  return result;
  }
```

нужно переделать ее так, чтобы она принимала значения uint8_t, а возвращала uint32_t. Напрямую заменить не выходит, функция начинает выдавать неверные ответы.

Скажем, есть a = 6, b = 3. И если просто заменить типы, то результат получится 450. Логичного объяснения, почему выдается именно такое число, я не нашел.

Comment: А почему вы не хотите передавать в нее `uint8_t`? Сконвертируется запросто, отработает, вернет верное значение... :) Почему нужно именно на входе типы `uint8_t`?

Comment: Не моя прихоть, так нужно преподавателю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш пример с заменой типов у меня работает. Правда, когда начинаю умножать большие числа, он перестает работать. Переполнение происходит, если результат произведения > 511. Поэтому я ввожу временную переменную, которую дальше и сдвигаю влево. Поэтому мои изменения следующие:

```
uint32_t mult(uint8_t a, uint8_t b) {
    uint32_t result = 0;
    uint32_t tmpA = a;
    while (b != 0) {
        if (b & 0x1 == 0x1)
            result += tmpA;

        b >>= 1;
        tmpA <<= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Действительно работает, с заменой получился хитрый код. Правда теперь нужно в main соответствующие переменные создать с типом int (с uint8_t не захотело работать), но это никакой роли не играет, т.к. нужна была ф-ия. Благодарю!